# While loop inside if/else

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

```
    while(playerTwoHealth > 0 && playerOneHealth > 0){
        changeScreen("Player1's Turn", "<button id='player1Attack'>Attack</button><button id='player1Defend'>Defend</button>");
        $("#player1Attack").click(function(){
            var successfulAttack = alert("Did you get this question right?");
            if(successfulAttack === true){
                playerTwoHealth = playerTwoHealth - 1;
                if(playerTwoHealth === 0){
                     break;
                };
            }else{

            };
        });
    };
```

I'm making a educational mathematics game, and In this section of code, I am trying to test the reaction to questions being asked. The function `changeScreen` changes the title and paragraph sections of the screen to be the specified HTML. On line no. 7-9, the if/else statement is designed to test if a player's health has reached 0, and if it has, break the while loop declared on line 1. However, the break statement throws an illegal break statement error. Please post any suggestions on how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the click event outside of the loop. In fact you don't really need a break since the while loop condition will not be valid when health is 0

```
while(playerTwoHealth > 0 && playerOneHealth > 0){
    changeScreen("Player1's Turn", "<button id='player1Attack'>Attack</button><button id='player1Defend'>Defend</button>");

};

$("#player1Attack").click(function(){
    var successfulAttack = alert("Did you get this question right?");
    if(successfulAttack === true){
        playerTwoHealth = playerTwoHealth - 1;
           if(playerTwoHealth === 0){
                // Do stuff
           };
    } else {

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your break statement is inside a function which you are binding to the click event, so it's not inside the while loop. You should never bind events within a while loop, as this will try to bind the event every time it loops around.

Also, you might want to replace `alert`with `prompt`